# Read orientation of device even though portrait is only enabled

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

Is there any way to get the orientation of the phone itself without having all orientations selected as supported orientations.

For example, my app only supports portrait orientation. If a user turns their phone sideways to landscape mode, is there anyway I am able to know that?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried overriding anything related to your view controller? Specifically `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and `viewWillTransition(toSize:)`. These are the "typical" places to check anything orientation oriented.

Comment: Have you looked at `UIDevice`?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. My problem is only portrait orientation is the supported orientation, and i need to find a way to be able to tell when the user turns their phone sideways.

Comment: Understood. Still, **have** you tried anything? I usually ask for code on my first comment. You haven't shown any. So my next question is - *What have you tried? And can you be specific as to what isn't working?*